# Getting drug register information through API

Tags: data.gov, openfda, api, json, xml

I am trying to find the drug registration info. Is there any FDA API available to gather drug register data set.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if these are the data for which you are looking.

There is not an API of which I am aware. It would not be unreasonable to ask the [openFDA](https://github.com/FDA/openfda) team to add the following dataset: http://www.fda.gov/Drugs/InformationOnDrugs/ucm135778.htm

Or you can just download the zip file at the bottom of the page, the data is not that complex.

Comment: Drug  register info is not  available with openfda.